# Can we submit questions/suggestions for Bad Code Offsets here?

Tags: discussion

Seeing as how Atwood and Skeet are both charter members?  I'd like to suggest additional projects to donate to when buying bad code offsets...

Comment: Wait, what?    *scratches head*

Comment: @Adam: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Introducing-Bad-Code-Offsets.aspx

Comment: I thought it was a spoof at first, like http://www.cheatneutral.com/

Comment: you.have.got.to.be.kidding.me. http://codeoffsets.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please address suggestions directly to http://codeoffsets.com/ - contact form is http://codeoffsets.com/Contact.aspx

You might also consider responding to this question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/what-free-open-source-projects-should-we-financially-support

Comment: +1 - that's the right place; but you could also answer here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/what-free-open-source-projects-should-we-financially-support

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say "not in any way affiliated with..."

Comment: Thanks for the note, Jeff.  I've eliminated that phrase.

Comment: Wait...  If JA is asking a codeoffsets question here, then why can't I?  NO ACCEPT FOR YOU!

Comment: aw, I lose. :,-(

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it.  Nobody submits coding horror article ideas here (do they?).  I'm sure there's somewhere appropriate to do that at codeoffsets.com.

Comment: I've seen some stuff here that might conceivably qualify.  Not intentionally, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a chink in the Jon Skeet armor or is he just playing with us?  Surely Jon Skeet doesn't need bad code offsets.  He really can fly around in jets without polluting.

Comment: Compilers buy "Jon Skeet Offsets" to atone for any times they may fail him.

Comment: Man gno(stradamus|vice), you are on fire today

Comment: @gnos: +1 Insightful

Comment: Its a fun way to drive cash to OSS projects.  Broke the build?  Instead of a toilet seat on your door you have to buy 25 BCOs.